# d3js - Trouble with select().on('click')

Tags: javascript, dom, d3.js

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/FN2Ab/6/

In the html, I have a

```
<button id="start">start!</button>
```

to which I want to do

```
d3.select("#start").on('click',printTimers())
```

where printTimers is a function that .appends a timestamp to all

```
<div class="timer">.
```

However, the .on('click',printTimers()) isn't working. Instead of appending the timestamp whenever the start button is pressed, it appends the timestamp as soon as the page loads.

I'm pretty new to d3js and webdev, and I'm having fits trying to figure out where this is broken. The resources I've looked at have not been helpful; hopefully somebody can point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are calling the function when you try to bind it. Remove the parentheses after the function name, so that you send the function reference into the `on` method instead of the result of calling the method:

```
d3.select("#start").on('click', printTimers);
```